# sitemap.html won't autogenerate

Tags: html, sitemaps

My sitemap.html won't generate. We recently did a site migration from one magento platform to another so I'm thinking this could be a reason, but would love to hear any feedback from you all.

The sitemap.xml and robots.txt are all in place after we uploaded the files to server, so would this solve issue or do I need to download something like creare?

Thanks for your help,
-Reed

Answer (score 2):

Did you run magento cronjobs on server? Here you have how to setup cron in Magento https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19658054/how-to-set-up-a-cron-job-in-magento